# Incorrect values when calculating Taylor approximation for exponent in Python

Tags: python, math

I wrote two functions that are supposed to calculate e^(-x):

```
def taylor1(x, n=12):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum += ( (-x)**i) / math.factorial(i)
    return sum

def taylor2(x, n=12):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum += ( x**i) / math.factorial(i)
    return 1/sum
```

First one directly calculates e^(-x), while second one calculates 1/e^(x). In theory both functions should return same values, but that is not the case:

Output for taylor1():

```
Exponent value for x=0: 1.0
Exponent value for x=5: -0.3592084034792353
Exponent value for x=10: -1162.6235369568703
Exponent value for x=15: -122924.17654220779
Exponent value for x=20: -3271048.1165624503
Exponent value for x=25: -41115385.050203174
Exponent value for x=30: -322535734.84415585
```

Output for taylor2():

```
Exponent value for x=0: 1.0
Exponent value for x=5: 0.006774891102970596
Exponent value for x=10: 6.515712399651421e-05
Exponent value for x=15: 1.655747452084087e-06
Exponent value for x=20: 9.637493883917857e-08
Exponent value for x=25: 9.808057158702018e-09
Exponent value for x=30: 1.4649434456831522e-09
```

So basically, values calculated by `taylor2()` are much more accurate. Why is this happening?

Note: for values x=1, 2, 3, 4 both functions output roughly same values. After that values become noticeably different

Comment: `taylor2` is also wildly inaccurate, just less obviously so than `taylor1`. You're cutting off the series way too early, and probably using inadequate precision.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand second one is not precise either, but cant understand why there is that some much difference between the two (especially since I am using same value of `n` for both

Comment: Adding a bunch of huge positive numbers makes a huge positive number. Inverting that produces a very small number. You look at a very small number and think "looks good!", even though it's orders of magnitude off.

Comment: The values of `n` being comparable doesn't tell you much, since they're different expansions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235579/5085211) or [this one on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1124876/10816) for a comment on the inaccuracy of the first one.

Comment: @fuglede I think thats the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Ach113: That's *part* of the answer, and it would be the answer if you had used more terms, but you're using a completely inadequate number of terms. Even if you had infinite precision, trying to get away with only 12 terms of the series would have still produced results this awful.

Comment: @user2357112 I get that, I was not looking for a way to achieve maximum accuracy using 12 terms, I just noticed the difference between two methods, and wanted to know why that was happening.

Comment: @Ach113: But it's not the source of the difference either. The difference is just because you're computing two completely wrong huge numbers, but the second one has the right sign, and you only look at its reciprocal, so the result looks closer to right.

Comment: You're not using anywhere near enough terms for the precision loss issues in fuglede's links to be a significant factor.

Comment: @user2357112 But if I understand correctly if I used larger number second function would still be closer to the actual result right? And the reason for that difference would be the answer given in fuglede's link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200114/discussion-between-ach113-and-user2357112).